# Pl/sql need to put a IN parameter between ''?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have prepared a stored procedure like this (it's more complex but the concept is that I need a dynamic SQL):

```
PROCEDURE PROCTEST(
    P_TEST                         IN     VARCHAR2,
    P_RESULT                      OUT PCK1.CURSOR
);
```

All I'm trying to do is use the value (let's say 'mytest') to do a select.

```
MYSELECT:='SELECT * FROM MYTABLETEST WHERE MYCOL='||P_RESULT||;
```

The problem is that I get this error:

> ORA-00911: invalid character

Because if I print my select I get `SELECT * FROM MYTABLETEST WHERE MYCOL=mytest` and not what I need:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLETEST WHERE MYCOL='mytest'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should include a concatenation of quote inside the statement by adding ''''.

```
MYSELECT:='SELECT * FROM MYTABLETEST WHERE MYCOL='||''''||P_RESULT||'''';
```

Comment: It worked thanks! It seems to strange for me that a simple thing like this need such manipulation. I'm going to accept the answer if there isn't something better. Thank you again

Comment: This is the simplest way. :)

Comment: Why not just `myselect := 'select * from mytabletest where mycol = '''||p_result||'''';` (or better still, use a bind variable).

Answer (score 0):

A variation of the answer by @FerdinandGaspar is the following, which might be a bit more legible:

```
SQL_TEMPLATE := q'[ SELECT * FROM MYTABLETEST WHERE MYCOL = '{PARAM}' ]';
MYSELECT := Replace(sql_template, '{PARAM}', p_result);
```

It's important to mention that this interpolation approach is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. If the number of parameters is known, a preferable approach is to use parameters (sometimes called "bind variables") in the SQL statement, and pass the parameter values as part of an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement, like so:

```
MYSELECT := 'SELECT * FROM MYTABLETEST WHERE MYCOL = :param';
Execute Immediate myselect Using p_result;
```